# Bad image quality with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn, minimagick

I want to create the ability for the user to upload an image into a pdf which will be generated inside of the app. To do so I'm using `gem prawn` to pdf creation and `CarrierWave::MiniMagic` to create thumbnail versions of images for a Rails 6 app, and I've noticed loss of quality when the images are downsized.

original image:

[image: original]

the same image inside of pdf:

[image: pdf]

Such a bad quality is not acceptable for me. I don't know if it's a common problem but I've found a few posts without any resolution, is there any alternative solution/tool to handle it? I have been struggling with this problem for weeks.

I don't have nothing special in my uploader file:

```
class LogoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  EXTENSION_WHITELIST = %w[jpg jpeg png].freeze

  storage :file

  process convert: 'png'

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [300, 300]
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    EXTENSION_WHITELIST
  end
end
```

Comment: There is this option combine_options: {quality: 100} inside the size array, I don't know if it can help you. https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/450